# C++ Find struct in list using a string item?

Tags: c++, list, struct

I'm very new to c++ and I'm trying to figure how to find a struct inside a list using a string.

I have a struct like this:

```
struct entrada {
  string token;
  string lexema;
  string tipo;
};
```

and a list:

```
list<entrada> simbolos;
```

*Insert here some 'entrada' in 'simbolos'*

Let's say I want to search for a 'entrada' with a certain 'lexema', and cout the other strings. Is there a simple way to do this? Like a function or something. I did it using while/for, but it isn't how I want to do.

Comment: Do you want the search to be _efficient_ for large lists?  If so, you need a different data structure.  If not, the standard library won't be of much help (since it tries to provide efficient algorithms).

Comment: @DavisHerring it will be for a few elements. How could I do that? I can use a map too, it doesn't need to be a list.

Comment: Just clarify what do you mean with "simple". Simple in terms of the number of lines of code or code legibility?

Comment: Nobody can help You if You don't know what You want.

Comment: `std::find_if`. Google it.

Comment: @BiagioFesta code legibility would be perfect. But if something works, I'll try to understand the code.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk I know what I want, I'm trying to use a function that works, without using a while or for. Like a `std::find_if` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In accordance with your comments, the following snippet shows you a simple way to search an element into a container using the algorithm in the STL [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

```
auto match = std::find_if(simbols.cbegin(), simbols.cend(), [] (const entrada& s) {
  return s.lexema == "2";
});

if (match != simbols.cend()) {
  std::cout << match->token << '\n'
            << match->lexema << '\n'
            << match->tipo << '\n';
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/yOVojP)

At least *C++11* is required.

Comment: I'm all for meaningful names, and no magic constants. But `str_to_find`, seriously?

Comment: @StoryTeller How could I suppose the context for the question and give a meaningful name?
If you can suggest me I'll be able to change the answer :P

Comment: `return s.lexema == "2";`. This is a case where the extra name does nothing.