# C++ Find a string in struct list with old compiler GCC 4.4.0

Tags: c++, list, struct, find

I am working on a program that have an struct based list that stores some file attributes data.

```
struct files {
  string name;
  string size;
  string owner;
};
```

And the list variable is described below

```
list<files> myfilecollection;
```

The thing that I want to do is to check if some determined file name is contained within the myfilecollection. Basically I checked this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46268626/c-find-struct-in-list-using-a-string-item) post and tried to write this function:

```
bool isFileSensible(const string& filename)
{
    auto match = std::find_if(myfilecollection.cbegin(), myfilecollection.cend(), [name] (const files& s) {
        return s.name == filename;
    });

    return match != myfilecollection.cend();
}
```

This implementation works all right with the GCC 9.2.0 but I need to make this function work on the GCC 4.4.4 with are not even C++ 11 compliant. What is the best way to re-implement this function for the GCC 4.4.0?

Best regards,
F.Borges

Answer (score 3):

You are using `auto` and a lambda, which are both C++11. Luckily in your case, both can be replaced trivially.

Lambdas are basically just syntactic sugar for functor classes, so you can use instead:

```
struct compare_files_by_name {
    std::string target;
    compare_files_by_name(const std::string& target) : target(target) {}
    bool operator()(const files& f) {
        return f.name == target;
    }
};
```

And what `find_if` returns is a `list<files>::const_iterator`. If we put that together you get:

```
bool isFileSensible(const string& filename)
{
    compare_files_by_name comp(filename);
    std::list<files>::const_iterator match = std::find_if(myfilecollection.cbegin(), myfilecollection.cend(),comp);

    return match != myfilecollection.cend();
}
```

PS: Being used to `auto`, I find it strange to fully write out an iterator type. I would probably write it as

```
  return myfilecollection.cend() != std::find_if(....
```

simply to avoid spelling out the iterator type.

Answer (score 3):

A lambda is nothing more then a short form for writing a functor.  You can just revert back to writing a functor that behaves the same way like

```
bool isFileSensible(const string& filename)
{
    struct FindFilename
    {
        std::string filename;
        FindFilename(std::string filename) : filename(filename) {}
        bool operator()(const files& obj)
        {
            return obj.name == filename;
        }
    };
    std::list<files>::const_iterator match = std::find_if(myfilecollection.cbegin(), myfilecollection.cend(), FindFilename(filename));
    return match != myfilecollection.cend();
}
```

I've put `FindFilename` in the scope of the function so it does not pollute the global namespace.  If you want to reuse this functor elsewhere you can move it out into the global scope.

Comment: missing  `;` after `std::string filename` and you still have `auto`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Good spot.  Answer updated.

Comment: apart from you putting the opening brackets in the wrong place, our answers are almost identical :P

Comment: well I wanted to say that I like your inline definition of the comparator better, but isnt that also C++11 only?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 AFAIK this was always allowed.  At least gcc and clang compile it: https://godbolt.org/z/l74Uoo

Comment: yep it was my misunderstanding, so +1 for the inline definition ;)

Comment: what is the obj variable?

Comment: @fborges22 `obj` is the object that `find_if` passes to `FindFilename`'s `operator()`.

Comment: i am getting an error that is saying ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'file' with no type

Comment: @fborges22 Sorry about that, I had a typo.  It should have been `bool operator()(const files& obj)` not `bool operator()(const file& obj)`

Comment: now i am getting an error that the compiler can't find the find_if function and I included the <algorithm> what should we do in this case?

Comment: @fborges22 You'll need to post a new question with a [mre] and include the error message you get.  `find_if` is a C++03 function so it should work.

Comment: i am using a version that is older than C++03... i am trying to implement with for loop and see if its works... i will post the results soon

Comment: @fborges22 What are you using then?  GCC4.4 supports C++03 which does have `find_if`

Comment: i check and indeed my compiler has the find_if function however the error is saying this:
no matching function for call to 'find_if(std::_List_const_iterator<files>, std::_List_const_iterator<files>, isFileSensible(const std::string&)::FindFilename)'

Comment: @fborges22 OK.  Looks like your adaption is not correct.  If you post a new question with a [mre] we can help you get it fixed.  Trying to do that here in the comments is really hard to do that.